# Why merging multiple geometries using three.js, crashes Chrome?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to render thousands of 3D floating random sentences, so I'm creating about 100 Geometries and using them to create one mesh with thousands of them. It works for a few sentences, but when the number grows, Chrome crashes. Any help would be appreciated:

```
    var totalGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
    var geometrics = [];
    var materials = [];
    var totalGeometrics = 100;

    // Creating 100 Geometries 
    for(var i = 0; i < totalGeometrics; i++) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16), specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 50 } );
        materials.push(material);

        var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( getRandomSentence(), {
            size: 18,
            height: 2,
            curveSegments: 0,
            font: "helvetiker",
            weight: "normal",
            style: "normal",
            bevelThickness: 0   ,
            bevelSize: 0,
            bevelEnabled: false
        });

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        geometrics.push(mesh)
    }

    // Merging 1,000 Geometries
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

        for(var g = 0; g < totalGeometrics ; g++) {

            var clonedMesh = geometrics[g].clone();
            clonedMesh.position.set(Math.random() * 2000 - 1000,Math.random() * 2000 - 1000,Math.random() * 2000 - 1000);


            clonedMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            clonedMesh.updateMatrix();

            totalGeom.merge(clonedMesh.geometry, clonedMesh.matrix, g);



        }
    }

    scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(totalGeom, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)));
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Nope - just the "Aw, Snap" - something went wrong error message

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop.

Comment: How does an infinite loop sounds like :)

Comment: Like a PC being very busy doing nothing.

Comment: It's not anywhere in my code, or do you see something I don't? Is it a bug with Three.js?

Comment: Instead of using `MeshFaceMaterial` can you try it with `MeshBasicMaterial`?

Comment: Still the exact same problem

Comment: on a side note, why do you create all these meshes, when you only use their geometries before merging?

Comment: How would you go about it?